# How can i communicate a string from app domain of one project to app domain of another

Tags: c#, .net, events, publish-subscribe, appdomain

I have 2 projects - Project A and Project B such that Project A is referenced in Project B.

I want the App domain of A to send a string to the App domain of B by publishing/subscribing event.

I am clueless how to do that ? I have referenced this blog [https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/sending-events-through-application-domain-boundary/
] but here both the app domains communicate within the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - I think the best way to do that is to create a Web Service on Project B and consume it on Project A. It can be a simple Rest API with the services you need to execute.

Option 2 - [Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples). You can communicate the two projects with sockets, one acts as server and the other as client.

Option 3 - WebSockets. It is a bit more complicated than the other two but it provides a good way to make a real-time connection between two projects that don't even have to be hosted in the same server.

Comment: I want the communication to happen through AppDomains in a pub sub way

Comment: Yes, you can use any of the options mentioned above to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ZeroMQ's Request-Reply.

server example: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:hwserver

client example: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:hwclient

For one server - multiple clients, consider Publish-Subscribe structure.